# Sort in GreenDAO

Tags: android, database, greendao

Raw query:

```
SELECT * FROM SAVED_JOB2 S, JOB J WHERE J._id=S._id ORDER BY DATE_SAVED DESC
```

How can I achieve sort for column in JOIN table. I have tried:

```
QueryBuilder<Job> queryBuilder = daoSession.queryBuilder(Job.class);
queryBuilder.join(JobDao.Properties.Id, SavedJob2.class, SavedJob2Dao.Properties.Id);
List<Job> list = queryBuilder1.list();
```

This normal JOIN works perfect. But I need to sort for `date_saved` column in table `SavedJob`.

I tried to add this line:

```
queryBuilder.orderDesc(SavedJob2Dao.Properties.date_saved);
```

But this line returns this error:

> Property 'date_saved' is not part of com.xxx.xxx.db.JobDao

```
Table JobDao: 
id (PK)
title
description
requirements
allowance
type
status

Table SavedJobDao:
id (PK autoincrement)
j_id (FK to JabDao)
date_saved
status
```

Comment: Ahow the class `JobDao`

Comment: @Jens tables are updated

Comment: GreenDAO works on object structure, not on tables. So we Need the Java classes not the tables

Comment: Did you mean I need to create a Java class with consists of all attributes in both table? @Jens

Comment: I guess you have it `com.xxx.xxx.db.JobDao`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any JOIN with greenDao. It works with objects, so in your savedJob you should have an object Job instead job_id.

So you can order by date_saved, but searching in savedJob only, you don't need either JOIN.

There are a lot of examples. And the official doc is awesome!.

Comment: Did I need to alter my table structure in auto generator?

Comment: Yes! here you have a simple example: http://www.oscargarrucho.com/blog/2016/base-de-datos-con-greenDao/